# Dependent template names and C++20 ADL

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20, argument-dependent-lookup

Consider the following example:

```
namespace N {
    template<class>
    struct C { };

    template<int, class T>
    void foo(C<T>);
}

template<class T>
void bar(N::C<T> c) {
    foo<0>(c);
}

int main() {
    N::C<void> c;
    bar(c);
}
```

Both GCC and Clang fail to compile this code under C++17 standard (with `-Werror`), because (according to my understanding) in C++17 ADL doesn't work when explicit template arguments `<...>` are present (unless a name is already established as a template name), so `foo` is a non-dependent name that is not found.

In C++20, the ADL rules have changes, and explicit template arguments don't prevent ADL. Now it seems that `foo` becomes a dependent name that should be resolvable via ADL. However, GCC and Clang have different opinions about the validity of this code. CLang compiles it without errors, but GCC (10.2, `-std=c++2a`) complains:

> `error: 'foo' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'N::foo'?`

In C++17 mode, Clang produces the following warning:

> `warning: use of function template name with no prior declaration in function call with explicit template arguments is a C++20 extension`

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M5r95f).

I have three related questions:

1. Which compiler is right and why?
2. In C++17, is `foo` in `foo<0>(c)` considered as a dependent name?
3. In C++20, is `foo` in `foo<0>(c)` considered as a dependent name?

Comment: Fwiw: [gcc trunc](https://godbolt.org/z/qfoq4n) in C++20 mode compiles it too so it seems they added that feature after 10.2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is [P0846](https://wg21.link/p0846), which is a C++20 feature. It appears that gcc does not implement this yet.

It's not a question of dependent name or not, it's a question of does the compiler know that `foo` refers to a template or not, and so is `foo<` doing a comparison or is it starting to do template parameters.

In C++17, the compiler had to already know that `foo` was a template-name (which you could accomplish by adding `using N::foo;`) in order to perform ADL, in C++20 that's no longer true - now the rule is that if unqualified lookup finds a template *or nothing*, we also consider it to be a template.

---

The dependence of `foo` didn't change as a result of this paper. In `foo<0>(c);`, `foo` is still a dependent name. The rule in [[temp.dep]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.dep) from C++17 was:

> In an expression of the form:
>
> `postfix-expression ( expression-listopt )`
>
> where the *postfix-expression* is an *unqualified-id*, the *unqualified-id* denotes a *dependent name* if
>
> - any of the expressions in the *expression-list* is a pack expansion,
> - any of the expressions or *braced-init-lists* in the *expression-list* is type-dependent, or
> - the *unqualified-id* is a *template-id* in which any of the template arguments depends on a template parameter.

The second bullet applies here - `c` is type-dependent. The C++20 wording is the same. The issue here wasn't that `foo` wasn't dependent in C++17. It's just that the rule was when we `foo<`, we don't *know* that `foo` is a template, so it's considered the less-than-operator, and that then fails.

Comment: But is `foo` a dependent name? If all names fall into two categories, this should be a valid question.

Comment: @Evg In C++17 it's also dependent... if lookup happened to find a template such that this expression could parse correctly. The "dependency" of the name didn't change as a result of this paper.