# using namespace std causes boost pointer cast to trigger ADL in c++17 standard

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, c++20, argument-dependent-lookup

I have a simple code with inheritance and `shared_ptr` from boost library. With standard c++20, the code compiles fine. The function calls to `static_pointer_cast` and `dynamic_pointer_cast` compiles without prepended `boost::` namespacing -- these function calls work because of ADL (Argument Dependent Lookup).

But with standard c++17, the code will not compile. I would assume that ADL wasn't implemented, or implemented differently, then. But then, if I add `using namespace std`, the code compiles fine. My question is: what does `std` have to do with `boost` library's function call?

Here is the online compiler so you can play around by commenting in and out the `using namespace std;` line: https://godbolt.org/z/cz8Md5Ezf

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

// using namespace std;

class Animal {
public:
  Animal()
  {}
  virtual ~Animal()
  {}
  void speak()
  {
    std::cout << "I am an animal\n";
  }
};

class Dog : public Animal {
public:
  Dog()
  {}
  void bark()
  {
    std::cout << "Gheu --> ";
  }
  void speak()
  {
    bark();
    Animal::speak();
  }
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<Animal> AnimalPtr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr<Dog> DogPtr;

int main()
{
  AnimalPtr ap = boost::make_shared<Animal>();
  DogPtr dp = boost::make_shared<Dog>();

  AnimalPtr ap1 = static_pointer_cast<Animal>(dp);
  DogPtr dp1 = dynamic_pointer_cast<Dog>(ap1);

  return 0;
}
```

And if you are thinking, "Well, if using namespace std removes the errors, then those pointer casting calls must be from the std library." I thought so too. But looking through gdb, I saw that no, with `using namespace std`, those functions are definitely called from boost library.

[image]

Comment: [Clang compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/jYo7Yb7n8) with the warning `use of function template name with no prior declaration in function call with explicit template arguments is a C++20 extension`. This question here seems to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67975598/3740047) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65225172/3740047) one.

Comment: semi-duplicate. Those questions do not mention the effect of `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Related, too: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60580782/why-cant-i-call-a-template-friend-function-with-explicit-template-arguments).

Comment: Seems like this is a good addition to [Why is using namespace std considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When the compiler sees a `<` after an identifier in an expression (such as in `static_pointer_cast<Animal>(dp)`) it needs to figure out whether `<` refers to the relational less operator or whether it is the start of a template argument list.

If a template is found by usual unqualified name lookup (not ADL), then the latter is assumed to be the case. But what if no template is found?

Before C++20, if the lookup did not find a template, it was assumed that the name does not refer to a template and that the following `<` is therefore the less operator.

In your original case that wouldn't make sense. For example there is nothing that `static_pointer_cast` can refer to as operand to `<`. So it will fail with a more or less clear error message depending on the compiler.

With `using namespace std;` it may be possible that the compiler implicitly included `std::static_pointer_cast` (from `<memory>`) with one of the headers you included explicitly (there is no guarantee) or it may be that the boost headers include `<memory>`. If that happened, then the unqualified lookup for `static_pointer_cast` will find it and because it is a template, `<` after it will be considered to start a template argument list instead of being the relation operator. Then it is clear that the whole expression is an unqualified function call with template argument list.

Since C++20, if the lookup does not find anything or finds any function at all, then it is also assumed that a `<` following the name introduces a template argument list.

With the interpretation as template argument list and therefore function call, normal unqualified name lookup and ADL for unqualified function calls will be done, which finds both `boost::shared_pointer_cast` (via ADL) and `std::shared_pointer_cast` if you are using `using namespace std;`, but because you are passing a `boost::shared_ptr` the `std` version, which requires a `std::shared_ptr` argument, will not be viable and the `boost` version will always be chosen by overload resolution. This part is unchanged with C++20.

Note that this is a breaking change in C++20. In some unusual situations you might have wanted `<` after a function name to actually refer to the relational operator which would now require parenthesizing the function name. See [[diff.cpp17.temp]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/diff.cpp17.temp) for an example.